# Отсутствуют кнопки у Alertdialog

Tags: java, android

Внизу диалога выделено место под кнопку, ее не видно но она кликабельна

```
public class timer extends DialogFragment {

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_timer, null)).setPositiveButton(
            R.string.textButtonDialog, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }
    );
    return builder.create();


}
```

Код диалога

```
public class forTimer extends Fragment {

public Chronometer timerOtd;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.laytimer, container, false);

    timerOtd= rootView.findViewById(R.id.timer);
    timerOtd.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    timerOtd.start();
    timerOtd.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
            long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
                    - timerOtd.getBase();

            if (elapsedMillis > 2000) {

                try {
                    Uri current = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
                    Ringtone currentRingtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getActivity(), current);
                    currentRingtone.play();

                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                timerOtd.stop();
            }

        }

    });

    return rootView;

}
```

Фрагмент с таймером

```
public void startTimer(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new timer();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timer");

}
```

Вызываю таймер методом onClck

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="aranea.upnotealfa.timer">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/forLogoInDialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoInDialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/upnoteactive"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/underloogo"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="aranea.upnotealfa.forTimer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:layout="@layout/laytimer" />
</LinearLayout>
```

XML диалога

UPD Попробовал перенести код в новый проект- все отображает отлично, без ошибок

Comment: В Java имена классов настоятельно рекомендуется писать с большой буквы, если свой код вы собираетесь показывать кому то еще, иначе воспринимать ваш код становится серьезной проблемой.

Comment: @pavlofff "я не волшебник, а только учусь", поэтому не знаю еще правил хорошего тона программистов. Спасибо за совет, буду знать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разобрался. Всего лишь цвет текста диалога- colorAccent. А в моем проекте это белый. Поэтому кнопок не было видно. Решил сделать так:

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
}
```